Error while building a program which should output assigned domino tiles for each player in Java
So, I am a total beginner in Java. I need a program that takes a number of players as an input. Then assuming there are 91 domino tiles each with two squares with dots ranging from 0 to 12 in each square. We divide the deck of tiles so that each player has as many tiles as possible, that means INT(91/numberOfPlayers). The output should be simple: 1st. player: 1-9,4-12,10-2,.... 2nd player: 4-6,1-12,7-8,...  Here is my code:
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Domino {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");
            int NumOfPlayers = scanner.nextInt();
            int CardsPerPlayer = Math.round(91/NumOfPlayers);
            System.out.println(CardsPerPlayer);
        }}

        class Tile {
            private int square1; //value of first square
            private int square2; //value of second square
            
            //class constructor
            public Tile(int first, int second) {
             square1 = first;
             square2 = second;
            }
            
           //transform to string
            public String toString() {
                 return square1 + "-" + square2;
            }
           }
           class Deck {
            String[][] twoD_arr = new String[13][13];
            for (int i=0; i<=12; i++){
                for (j=0; j<=12; j++){
                    twoD_arr[i][j]=String.valueOf(i) + "-" + String.valueOf(j);
                    System.out.println(twoD_arr \n);

                }
            }
           }
}}

As of right now, I have an error just after new String[13][13];. The debugger states that instead of ; there should be }. And because of this, I don't see what the cycle outputs. I assume it should be a sequence like this: 0-0 0-1 0-2 ... 12-10 12-11 12-12 of length 91. But at the same time, the twoD_arr is defined as two dimensional array. I'd like for twoD_arr to be a 1D array of all possible combinations of dominoes, so that I could hand each player appropriate shuffled dominoes and output it. Although I am not sure how to string all this together.

The for (int i=0;... statement does not belong to any method.; j is undeclared and System.out.println(twoD_arr \n); is incorrect. Please check the code.

Also, break your question into two as you're currently asking two questions: "1. why the compiler is signaling a certain error?" and "2. how to make twoD_arr from a bidimensional array to a single dimension array?" Address one problem at the time.

The main error in your code is the for loop right after the declaration of the twoD_arr attribute in the Deck class. Also, there is a missing declaration of j in the nested loop, and a newline \ n not enclosed within double quotes with a space.
class Deck {
    String[][] twoD_arr = new String[13][13];

    //This code section cannot be placed after the attribute declaration
    //unless it's placed in an instance initializer block
    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        //j has not been declared
        for (j = 0; j <= 12; j++) {
            twoD_arr[i][j] = String.valueOf(i) + "-" + String.valueOf(j);
            //\ n does not represent a new line
            System.out.println(twoD_arr\ n);

        }
    }
}

If you want to initialize your array, you need to do that in an instance block initializer, a class' constructor, or a dedicated method.
Moreover, as a side note:

you should iterate over an array via its length property instead of a fixed literal. This is because length holds the number of elements that an array can store, making your code less error-prone.

If you want to print an array with all its elements, you cannot just pass it to the println() method. This will only invoke the default Object.toString() method implicitly, printing the class name followed by the hex representation of the array's hashcode. In your case, you should use Arrays.deepToString(), and not Arrays.toString(). This is because you're attempting to print the content of a multidimensional array. In fact, Arrays.deepToString() returns a string representation of the given array with all its nested arrays. While, Arrays.toString() returns only a string populated with the Object.toString() of each sub-array. Instead, if you were attempting to print just a single element in i-th and j-th position, you need to reference it via its corresponding indexes twoD_arr[i][j].


String[][] mat = new String[][]{
        new String[]{"hello", "world"},
        new String[]{"hola", "mundo"}
};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(mat));  // [[hello, world], [hola, mundo]]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mat));      // [[Ljava.lang.String;@6e2c634b, [Ljava.lang.String;@37a71e93]

Your code could be re-written as follows:
1. Instance block initializer
class Deck {
    String[][] twoD_arr = new String[13][13];

    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= twoD_arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= twoD_arr[i].length; j++) {
                twoD_arr[i][j] = i + "-" + j;
                //Either print the full array...
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoD_arr) + "\n");
                //... or print the i-th j-th element
                System.out.println(twoD_arr[i][j] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

2. Class constructor
class Deck {
    String[][] twoD_arr = new String[13][13];

    public Deck(){
        for (int i = 0; i <= twoD_arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= twoD_arr[i].length; j++) {
                twoD_arr[i][j] = i + "-" + j;
                //Either print the full array...
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoD_arr) + "\n");
                //... or print the i-th j-th element
                System.out.println(twoD_arr[i][j] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

3. Dedicated method
class Deck {
    String[][] twoD_arr = new String[13][13];

    public void initArray(){
        for (int i = 0; i <= twoD_arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= twoD_arr[i].length; j++) {
                twoD_arr[i][j] = i + "-" + j;
                //Either print the full array...
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoD_arr) + "\n");
                //... or print the i-th j-th element
                System.out.println(twoD_arr[i][j] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

On a final note, here is a link to Java naming conventions. A better name for your twoD_arr variable could be twoDimArr.

I think, it makes better sense to have this for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {  written as for (int i = 0; i < twoD_arr.length; i++) {. Similarly for the inner loop, like this: for (int j = 0; j < twoD_arr[i].length; j++) {.

System.out.println(twoD_arr + "\n"); - How does this work and what does it print? To print array contents you will need java.util.Arrays.toString(). In this case, something like this: System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoD_arr[i]) + "\n");

I didn't address the many logical errors, since the question is about compilation errors. But, yes, you're absolutely right @prasad_. Also, I didn't point out the issues with the naming convention adopted. I'll expand my answer later.

I understand this is you work in progress. Currently you have several issues in your code, I will pinpoint those that I see:
  class Deck {
    String[][] twoD_arr = new String[13][13];
    for (int i=0; i<=12; i++){
    ^^^ -- !!!

you cant have a for loop in a class body it should be inside a method or a constructor.
Second error is that you are missing the type of variable in inner loop:
for (j=0; j<=12; j++){
     ^ -- !!!

it should be int.
Then you try to print array with an \n, which is also not valid:
System.out.println(twoD_arr \n);  

(Compiler would accept System.out.println(twoD_arr[i][i]);)
Last thing is that you try to create a 2d array:
String[][] twoD_arr = new String[13][13];

instead of 1d - which you say you want. To make 1d array use for example: String[] a = new String[13*13];
You also dont use Deck or Tile anywhere.
Explanation how to code this is beyond this answer, you probably need to read more on java. All what I have written is actually what compiler would tell you with its compilation errors.
Below is a link to solution which maight spoil you some usefull practice coding it: http://tpcg.io/_AT9NVC
